# No image appears when using converter from file path to image

Tags: c#, windows, image, xaml, datatemplate

I am currently trying to display images in my Windows 8 application. I have a method which populates a property of type `List<string>` with a number of paths to images. I wish to display these images on screen.

Thus, I have implemented a converter to go from string to image. It correctly enters the converter, hits the breakpoint in the `Convert` method, but still nothing appears on screen.

Here is the code from my Converter :

```
namespace TestApp.Converters
{
    public sealed class StringToImageConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType,
                              object parameter, string path)
        {
            try
            {
                return new BitmapImage(new Uri((string)value));
            }
            catch
            {
                return new BitmapImage();
            }
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType,
                                  object parameter, string path)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

From my XAML file :

```
    <common:LayoutAwarePage
        ...
        xmlns:converters="using:TestApp.Converters"
         DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
        <Page.Resources>
            <converters:StringToImageConverter x:Key="StringToImageConverter"> </converters:StringToImageConverter>
        </Page.Resources>
...
  <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=test}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="4"
              HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Image Source="{Binding Converter={StaticResource StringToImageConverter}}" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                </ItemsControl>
...
```

The `List<string>` of image paths is called `test` and is in the code behind of the xaml file.

Here is a simple version of the relevant code from my code behind xaml.cs file :

```
    public List<string> test { get; set; }

    public MainPage()
    {
        test = new List<string>();
        test.Add("C:\\Users\user\\Pictures\\test.jpg");
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }
```

Thanks very much for any and all help with this :)

Comment: Have you verified that the Convert() method finishes without throwing an exception and that it creates a valid BitmapImage?

Comment: @JLRishe I have, a valid .bmp is made, no exception :)

Comment: Try setting width and height for the image (for testing, say, 100 for each). Did it help?